# apply subscripting to text data type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, text, types, subscript

Hope I read it correctly.
Subscripting can be used in text type, like `select name[1]` will get the first character of the text column `name`?
Now this will not work. Probably need a function?
when I do it in psql.

> ERROR:  42804: cannot subscript type text because it does not support subscripting
> LOCATION:  transformContainerSubscripts, parse_node.c:275

So, how to make subscripting available for text data type?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/

> Subscripting can now be applied to any data type for which it is a
> useful notation, not only arrays. In this release, the jsonb and
> hstore types have gained subscripting operators.

Comment: The release notes mention three types: arrays, hstore and jsonb - `text` is neither of them. So, no, you did not read it correctly.

Comment: for subscripting text data you can use the function `substring()` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  cannot subscript type text because it does not support subscripting

When I tried to get the 2nd character `b` as shown below:

```sql
SELECT ('abc'::TEXT)[2]; -- Error
```

So, I created an array with these ways below, then I could get the 2nd character `b` without error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406989/declare-an-array-in-postgresql/77723752#77723752) explains how to declare and use an array in detail:

```sql
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c']::TEXT[])[2]; -- b
```

```sql
SELECT ('{a,b,c}'::TEXT[])[2]; -- b
```

```sql
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c', ',')::TEXT[])[2]; -- b
```