# Declare an array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to do 3 actions (2 delete and 1 update) on an array of ent_id. This array is build in my script in the select.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_script()
  RETURNS VOID
AS $$
DECLARE
  all_ent bigint[];
BEGIN
  SELECT ent_id INTO all_ent FROM entretiens ent WHERE ent.ent_statut = 'T';

  RAISE INFO 'Start';

  DELETE FROM documents WHERE ent_id IN (all_ent);

  DELETE FROM comite WHERE ent_id IN (all_ent);

  DELETE entretiens ent SET ent_statut = 'N' WHERE ent_id IN (all_ent);

  RAISE INFO 'End';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT run_script();
```

When I run the script I have this error:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "535030"
Détail : Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You looking for [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Set to array selected field values:

```
select ARRAY(
    select ent_id
    from entretiens ent
    where ent.ent_statut = 'T'
) into all_ent;
```

Use array on queries:

```
delete
from documents
where ent_id in (select aaa from unnest(all_ent) tb(aaa));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Memos:

- An array has values from `[1]` but not from `[0]` so `[0]` returns `NULL`.
- Basically, you should use type conversion to create an array except when you declare a non-empty array in a `DECLARE` clause in a function, procedure or `DO` statement because the type may be different from your expectation and there is some case which you cannot create an array without type conversion.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) explains arrays in detail.

You can create and use an array with these ways below:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[0]; -- NULL
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- b
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[2:4]; -- {b,c,d}
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[:4]; -- {a,b,c,d}
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[2:]; -- {b,c,d,e}
SELECT (ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[:]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `VARCHAR[]`(`CHARACTER VARYING[]`).
- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, the type of the array above is `TEXT[]`.

Or:

```sql
SELECT '{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[0]; -- NULL
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- b
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[2:4]; -- {b,c,d}
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[:4]; -- {a,b,c,d}
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[2:]; -- {b,c,d,e}
SELECT ('{a,b,c,d,e}'::VARCHAR[])[:]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `VARCHAR[]`(`CHARACTER VARYING[]`).
- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, the value above is not an array and the type of the value above is `unknown`.

Or:

```sql
SELECT string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[0]; -- NULL

SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[2]; -- b
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[2:4]; -- {b,c,d}
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[:4]; --  {a,b,c,d}
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[2:]; -- {b,c,d,e}
SELECT (string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e', ',')::VARCHAR[])[:]; -- {a,b,c,d,e}
```

*Memos:

- The type of the array above is `VARCHAR[]`(`CHARACTER VARYING[]`).
- If you omit `::VARCHAR[]`, the type of the array above is `TEXT[]`.
- Don't put any spaces in the 1st argument of [string_to_array()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTION-STRING-TO-ARRAY) otherwise the values separated by `,` have spaces.

In addition, even if you set `VARCHAR(2)[2]` to the array, the result is the same as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR(2)[2];
    array
-------------
 {a,b,c,d,e}
(1 row)
```

And, the type of the array is `VARCHAR[]`(`CHARACTER VARYING[]`) rather than `VARCHAR(2)[2]`(`CHARACTER VARYING(2)[2]`) as shown below. *You can use [pg_typeof()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) to check the type of a value:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof(ARRAY['a','b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR(2)[2]);
      pg_typeof
---------------------
 character varying[]
(1 row)
```

And, even if you set `::TEXT` to `'a'`, the type of `'a'` is `VARCHAR`(`CHARACTER VARYING`) rather than `TEXT` as shown below because the outer type conversion `VARCHAR[]` is prioritized:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT (ARRAY['a'::TEXT,'b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[1];
 array
-------
 a
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof((ARRAY['a'::TEXT,'b','c','d','e']::VARCHAR[])[1]);
     pg_typeof
-------------------
 character varying
(1 row)
```